# Performance issue with site speed 'w3p.exe’ process –reaches 99/100%

Tags: performance, load, publishing

My site goes slow and stops access certain services externally if we check the Process monitor we see that it is normally due to the ‘w3p.exe’ process – which is the background process for running the website – it regularly reaches 99/100% - killing the process/restarting the WebPublishing service reolves tis – my webhost says this can only be due to bad coding ....can someone comment on this ??…

Comment: If kragen2uk is correct that this can be managed by changing the worker process recycle in IIS, this question probably belongs on serverfault.  On the other hand, it *could* be bad coding...  It's hard to say with the details we're given.  However, you might want to keep your webhost happy - it is entirely within their right - and probably in their terms of service - that they can terminate any account that "abuses" system resources.

Answer (score 1):

When performance testing a reasonably straightforward website (coded in ASP.Net) I saw it slow to a crawl with memory use going through the roof over time. Each time recycling the w3wp process restored performance back to normal.

I never got around to figuring out why (the load we were testing with was way above normal, and it could have been worked around anyway by recycling the w3wp service more frequently), but my bet would have been that it was viewstate causing the slowdown. A lot of pages had very large viewstate which wasnt being used in any way - I can fesably see how loading large viewstate values might cause memory related performance degregation over time.

Answer (score 0):

What language is the site coded in? I recently ran into the same problem on a server running IIS6/PHP and found the following bug -

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37575

Upgrading PHP to 5.3 solved the issue.

Comment: it is in ASP & SQL Server 2005